# Relation between characteristic function and mean

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $\phi$ is its characteristic
>   funciton.
>
> Does $\phi'(0)=ia$ mean $EX=a$?

If not, is there any counterexample?

I think the counterexample will exist in Cauchy random variable because
its mean does not exist but its characteristic exists $\phi(t)=e^{-|t|}$.
But this does not have a derivative at $0$.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Moments).

Comment: @drhab I had a look at the link. I know 'If the 1st momentum exists, $\phi'(0)=i*EX$'. But I'm asking the opposite way.

Comment: I am not sure about the opposite, but it is clear that Cauchy does *not* provide a counterexample, right?

Comment: @drhab Yeah. No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the brilliant book of W.Feller "An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications", in Vol.2, Chapter XVII, paragraph 2a, you can find the proof of the following theorem (A.Zygmund (1947), E.J.Pittman (1956)):

> **Theorem.** Each of the following three conditions implies the other two.
>
> 1. $\phi'(0)=i\mu$.
> 2. As $t\to\infty$,
>
> $$t\left[1-F(t)+F(-t)\right]\to 0, \quad \int_{-t}^t xF\{dx\}\to \mu. $$
>
> 3. The average $(X_1+\dots+X_n)/n$ tends in probability to $\mu$.

So, we can simply construct a pdf that satisfies (2) but s.t. the expectation does not exist. Say, we can consider symmetric distribution with cdf 
$$
F(t)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{e}{2|t|\ln(|t|)} & \text{if } t<-e\\\quad \dfrac12 & \text{if } -e\leq t\leq e\\ 1-\dfrac{e}{2t\ln(t)} & \text{if } t>e\end{cases}
$$
For $t>e$
$$t\left[1-F(t)+F(-t)\right]=\dfrac{e}{\ln(t)}\to 0 \text{ as } t\to\infty, 
$$
and symmetry implies that
$$\quad \int_{-t}^t xF\{dx\} =0 \text{ for any } t>0.$$

So, the condition (2) of the Theorem is fulfilled with $\mu=0$ and $\phi'(0)=0$.

But the expectation does not exist since $\left[1-F(t)+F(-t)\right]$   is not integrable on $\mathbb R_+$. You can see it directly: the pdf looks like
$$
f(t)=\frac{e}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\ln(|t|)+1}{t^2\ln^2(|t|)}, \ |t|>e,
$$
and 
$$
E|X|=2\int_e^\infty tf(t)dt =e\int_e^\infty \dfrac{\ln(t)+1}{t\ln^2(t)} \, dt = e\int_e^\infty \dfrac{\ln(t)+1}{\ln^2(t)} \, d(\ln(t))=+\infty.
$$

Comment: As is mentioned in every book with a title similar to *Counterexamples in probability and statistics*.

Comment: @Did You are rigtht. But as you can see in comments above, even some well-deserved colleagues are not aware of such examples.

Comment: This example is so complicated, not intuitive. Is there any other example?

Comment: Alas, it's the simplest example. If you look at the theorem cited  above, you will see that any example should lie in the small gap between the conditions: 
1) $tP(|X|>t)=t(1-F(t)+F(-t))\to 0$ (necessary condition for existence of derivative of c.f. at 0),
and
2) $P(|X|>t)=1-F(t)+F(-t)$ is integrable (necessary and sufficient for existence of $E[X]$). 
Any example must have tails of distribution which satisfy (1) and not satisfy (2), i.e. $P(|X|>t) \propto \frac{1}{tg(t)}$ is only valid, where $g(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to \infty$, but slower than any positive power of t. The logarithm is good.