# Convergence of the empirical average of iid random variables in probability implies integrability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be non-negative i.i.d. random variables and assume that $S_n=(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ converge to a real random variable $X$ in probability.

How can I prove that the expectation of $X_{k}$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, are finite?

Intuitively (by the weak law of large numbers), the random variable $X$ should be constant equal to $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$. Is this right? would this fact be helpful?

Comment: This is not true, in general. Here is an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2260862/

Comment: Thank you for pointing the nice example. However it does not apply to my case, since the example concerns to sum of real random variable whereas in my case the random variables are non-negative.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the requirement of non-negativity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer.

Claim: Let $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. non-negative RVs with $\mathbb{E}[X_1^{+}]=\infty$. Then $S_{n}=(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ converges to $\infty$ a.s.

So suppose that the $S_{n}$ with $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ i.i.d. and non-negative converges to a real random variable $X$ in probability but $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}]=\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{+}]=\infty$. The latter assumption and the claim assert that $S_{n}$ converges to $\infty$ a.s. and hence in probability. This contradicts to the fact that $S_{n}$ converges to $X$.

The claim follows in particular by the strong law of large numbers for integrable random variables:
Let $X_{n}^{\leq d}:=X_{n}I_{\left\{X_{n}\leq d\right\}}$, where $d>0$ and $I$ denotes the indicator function. $(X_{n}^{\leq d})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d. and integrable. Thus by the strong law of large numbers we have for $d>0$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X^{\leq d}_{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{E}[X^{\leq d}_{1}]\quad\text{as $n\rightarrow\infty$}\quad\text{a.s.}
\end{equation*} 
By monotone convergence Theorem, $\mathbb{E}[X^{\leq d}_{1}]$ converges to $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}]$ and hence diverges to $\infty$.